# How to change UICollectionViewCell selection of a non-visible cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is there any way to change the 'selected' member of a UICollectionViewCell that is not in the "visibleCells"?
(beside saving the Cell object of the last selected cell...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the selected status of an item you should call the method `selectItemAtIndexPath:` Items can be reused, so if you call the `setSelected` method of UICollectionViewCell, it might not select the right item.

```
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

If you want to deselect it you have this method:

```
[self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```